# Django reset password throws 500 error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have implemented the Reset password by using django ResetPassword. But It throws the 500 error. I don't know how to find the flow & fix it.

1.I have created the urls.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from django.urls import include, path

    from . import views

    app_patterns = [
        path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
        path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), 
        name='logout'),
        path('signup/', views.Signup.as_view(), name='signup'),
        path(
            'password_reset/',
            auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
            name='password_reset'
        ),]
```

Also I have created the HTML files (Refer [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toko3.png))

- password_reset_form
- password_reset_done
- password_reset_confirm
- password_reset_complete

I don't know what I'm missing here. Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the text. If you run the code on your development server with `DEBUG=False`, then you'll get a full stacktrace which will help track down the error. If you are running in production with `DEBUG=True`, you'll need to look at the logs or email sent to the site admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several views required to reset passwords. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) suggest that the easiest way to enable them is to include `django.contrib.auth.urls`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

If you want more control, you could include them individually. Look at the code for [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/af33fb250e9847f1ca8c0ba0d72671d76659704f/django/contrib/auth/urls.py) to see how to include them. For example the password reset urls would be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...    
    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Note that in your answer you have

```
app_patterns = [
    ...
]
```

Django will not use `app_patterns` automatically. You should have

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```